# Can I edit Java 2D components with Design view (Eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-2d

Can I edit Java2D codes in Design view like swing and awt components?

For example this line drawings:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Tester extends JPanel {
    public Tester() {
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        float[] dash1 = { 2f, 0f, 2f };

        g2d.drawLine(20, 40, 250, 40);

        BasicStroke bs1 = new BasicStroke(1, 
            BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, 
            BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND, 
            1.0f, 
            dash1,
            2f);
        g2d.setStroke(bs1);
        g2d.drawLine(20, 80, 250, 80);

      }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tester points = new Tester();

    // Just frame settings
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Line");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(points);
    frame.setSize(300, 250);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

The lines are not visible in the components or I can draw them only using code?

thanks

Comment: Are you using NetBeans? If so, please indicate that in the title, text *and* tags of your question.

Comment: Just change the  frame code like this jframe.add(points);

Comment: I am using eclipse.